# Using fetch inside an action within my component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm curious about how I could implement this, I'd like to not hit this API every time the page loads on the route, but would rather start the call on an action (I suppose this action could go anywhere, but it's currently in a component). I'm getting a server response, but having trouble getting this data inside my component/template. Any ideas? Ignore my self.set property if I'm on the wrong track there....Code below..Thanks!

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  res: null,
  actions: {
    searchFlight(term) {
      let self = this;
      let url = `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=PAR&destination=LON&departureDate=2018-09-25&returnDate=2018-09-28&adults=1&travelClass=BUSINESS&nonStop=true&max=2`;
      return fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
          'Authorization':'Bearer JO5Wxxxxxxxxx'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        self.set('res', response.json());
        return response.json();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved below...

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  flightResults: null,
  actions: {
    searchFlight(term) {
      let self = this;
      let url = `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=PAR&destination=LON&departureDate=2018-09-25&returnDate=2018-09-28&adults=1&travelClass=BUSINESS&nonStop=true&max=2`;
      return fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
          'Authorization':'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(flightResults => {
        this.set('flightResults', flightResults);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Prior to calling this.set, you may need to check that the component has not been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You might find ember-concurrency to be useful in this situation. See the [example](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/examples/autocomplete) of "Type-ahead search", modified for your example:

```
const DEBOUNCE_MS = 250;
export default Controller.extend({
  flightResults: null;
  actions: {
    searchFlight(term) {
    this.set('flightResults', this.searchRepo(term));
    }
  },
  searchRepo: task(function * (term) {
    if (isBlank(term)) { return []; }

    // Pause here for DEBOUNCE_MS milliseconds. Because this
    // task is `restartable`, if the user starts typing again,
    // the current search will be canceled at this point and
    // start over from the beginning. This is the
    // ember-concurrency way of debouncing a task.
    yield timeout(DEBOUNCE_MS);

    let url = `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=PAR&destination=LON&departureDate=2018-09-25&returnDate=2018-09-28&adults=1&travelClass=BUSINESS&nonStop=true&max=2`;

    // We yield an AJAX request and wait for it to complete. If the task
    // is restarted before this request completes, the XHR request
    // is aborted (open the inspector and see for yourself :)
    let json = yield this.get('getJSON').perform(url);
    return json;
  }).restartable(),

  getJSON: task(function * (url) {
    let xhr;
    try {
      xhr = $.getJSON(url);
      let result = yield xhr.promise();
      return result;

      // NOTE: could also write this as
      // return yield xhr;
      //
      // either way, the important thing is to yield before returning
      // so that the `finally` block doesn't run until after the
      // promise resolves (or the task is canceled).
    } finally {
      xhr.abort();
    }
  }),
});
```